# Google scripts call to function from sidebar button failing when user with permissions is not logged in as default user on google

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, google-account

I recently asked this question on stack [Google App Scripts - Function calls with google.script.run always failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66834738/google-app-scripts-function-calls-with-google-script-run-always-failing)

I was having trouble getting a button in the sidebar to launch a script in my code.gs. Turns out if I had the user that has permissions for that sheet set as default user in google everything worked perfect. But if I had my personal account set as default the function would fail.

Anyone know of a fix for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/66780096/1595451

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66491971/1595451 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/61256242/1595451